# Reusing a delegate component in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

I came across a weird problem when designing my application in QML. The following code works:

```
TableView {
  itemDelegate: Item {
    function a() {}
    Loader {}
  }
}
```

I have a bunch of functions, properties, and loaders in this item delegate which is an Item object. Problems arise when I try to reuse this delegate in a ListView. I can't reference it like this:

```
Item {
    id: myitem
    function a() {}
    Loader {}
}

TableView {
   itemDelegate: myitem
}

error: Unable to assign QQuickItem to QQmlComponent
```

This is because `itemDelegate` is a `Component`:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#itemDelegate-prop

So QML can convert an `Item` to `Component` when it's embedded, but not when it's referenced.

And I can't make it a component, since components can't have functions, loaders, properties etc.

How can I reuse my delegate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by wrapping the item inside the component:

```
Component {
   Item{...}
}
```

Comment: I'm also struggling with this issue but your code is not working for me because I actually have a `list` of `Component`s. In my case I have a `PageIndicator` with a `list` of `Image` type components inside and I'm trying to assign an element of that `list` to the `delegate` property. Have you ever used a container for assigning a value to a `delegate`?